# Rails прикрепление файла к форме

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Форма (Скрин) 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прикрепляю скрин ошибки 
[![введите сюда описание изображения][2]][2]

Работать с рельсами я начал вчера, поэтому не особо ещё понимаю. 
Вот модель:

```
 class Person < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :age, inclusion: { in: 17..65 }, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true }
  validates :datetime, presence: true
  has_attached_file :file, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }
end
```

Вот миграция:

```
  class CreatePeople < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :people do |t|
      t.string :name, null:false
      t.integer :age, null:false
      t.datetime :datetime, null:false
      t.attachment :file

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Строка на которую ссорится

```
 @person = Person.new(page_params)
```

И процедура (page_params)

```
     private
  def page_params
    params[:person].permit(:name, :age, :datetime, :file)
  end
```

Помогите пожалуйста

---

Пробовал по разному вытаскивать параметр, перерыл весь интернет, но не могу никак решить! 
Вот вытаскиваем параметры:

```
     private
  def page_params
      params[:person].permit(:name, :age, :datetime, :filek  => [:tempfile, :original_filename, :content_type, :headers])
  end
```

Вот ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Со второй ошибкой вы вполне можете разобраться самостоятельно, т. к. это явная опечатка. Я мог бы посоветовать запостить её отдельным вопросом, но как только поймёте в чём дело, хлопнете себя по лбу и попросите вопрос закрыть %)

Comment: я с преподавателем 2 часа сидел и не мог решить)  он так же не знает. Буду думать ...

Comment: Серьёзно? Посмотрите в ваш метод `page_params`, потом в свою миграцию. Потом ещё раз в `page_params`, потом ещё раз в миграцию. (Хотя в общем случае надо смотреть не в миграцию, а в схему базы, но это детали, да и схемы в вопросе нет)

Comment: а какая именно? Что в первом вопросе или во втором? Она много раз изменялась для достижение нужной цели)

Comment: Ошибка же во втором вопросе.

Comment: @D-side создал новый вопрос http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/605492/rails-не-работает-upload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ в [README Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#security-validations), привожу перевод:

> ### Валидации безопасности
>
> Благодаря отчёту [Егора Хомякова](http://homakov.blogspot.ru/) мы приняли меры по предотвращению загрузки данных неожиданного типа на ваш сервер путём подделывания `Content-Type`.
>
> ЗАМЕТЬТЕ: начиная с версии 4.0.0 все вложения должны *обязательно* проверяться валидацией на content_type, file_name, или же нужно явно указать, что их нет. *Paperclip выкинет ошибку*, если вы этого не сделаете.
>
> ```rb
> class ActiveRecord::Base
>   has_attached_file :avatar
>   # Проверить content-type
>   validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, content_type: /\Aimage/
>   # Проверить имя файла
>   validates_attachment_file_name :avatar, matches: [/png\z/, /jpe?g\z/]
>   # Отказаться от проверок
>   do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :avatar
> end
> ```
>
> Благодаря этому, Paperclip безопасен по умолчанию и развернёт людей, пытающихся играться с вашей файловой системой.

...что лишний раз намекает: **читайте документацию**.

Comment: Помогите, валидацию проходит (точнее, отключил ей), но не хочет создавать объект! Обновил пост

Comment: @Samuliak плохая идея. Её ж навязывают не просто так. В вопросе не наблюдаю никаких обновлений.

Comment: не думал, что вы быстро так ответите) уже обновил. Сейчас не делаю валидацию, пока не будет хоть так работать. Ведь не создает объект