# Rails не работает upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

Помогите! Такая ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Модель:

```
    class Person < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :age, inclusion: { in: 17..65 }, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true }
  validates :datetime, presence: true
  #has_attached_file :file, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }
  do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :filek
  #validates_attachment_file_name :filek, :matches => [/jpe?g\z/, /gif\z/, /png\z/]
end
```

Миграция:

```
    class CreatePeople < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :people do |t|
      t.string :name, null:false
      t.integer :age, null:false
      t.datetime :datetime, null:false
      t.attachment :filek, null:true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Код из вьюхе (находится в форме):

```
<%= p.input :filek, as: :file  %>
```

Метод выборки параметров (контролер, где ошибка):

```
     private
  def page_params
      params[:person].permit(:name, :age, :datetime, :filek  => [:tempfile, :original_filename, :content_type, :headers])
  end
```

Помогите пожалуйста... не могу решить второй день, перелазил весь инет и не могу найти рабочий вариант

---

schema.db

```
create_table "people", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name",               null: false
    t.integer  "age",                null: false
    t.datetime "datetime",           null: false
    t.string   "filek_file_name"
    t.string   "filek_content_type"
    t.integer  "filek_file_size"
    t.datetime "filek_updated_at"
    t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
  end
```

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

дебаг:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что такое `filek`? Это есть в БД? (`db/schema.rb` или структуре таблиц) "Лазить в инете" бесполезно, если вы понятия не имеете, что ищете :)

Comment: filek - это файл. Сначала была переменная "file", но была мысль что не записывает данные из за название) и она была переименованная. Прикрепляю schema.rb к основному посту. Использую гем paperclip для загрузки файла

Comment: Не одно так другое. Ранее у вас хоть были `file` и `filek`, теперь у вас почему-то закомментирован `has_attached_file`.

Comment: насколько я понимаю, нужно явно указывать валидацию. Но если не хочется этого делать, тогда нужно указать, что в валидации не нуждаюсь. Её я забрал, что бы проверить будет ли вообще загружать файл. А в дальнейшем уже буду валидацию делать )

Comment: Так а указание того факта, что к модели вообще прикрепляется файл, зачем убрали?

Comment: забрал комментирование, и все равно такая же ошибка (

Comment: все, уже ошибки нет! Но в базе не отображаются данные, что файл записан. Сейчас к главному посту прикреплю скрин

Comment: Возьмите отладчик, остановитесь посреди `create` и проверьте, что возвращает `page_params`.

Comment: сделал, как вы и написали, оказывается объект пустой.Хотя  page_params имеет все параметры и они верны

Comment: Какой объект пустой? И **воздержитесь от добавления в вопрос скриншотов без крайней на то необходимости**, или хотя бы обрезайте их до строго необходимой области.

Comment: @person и name (на скрине видно), но параметры переданы верно

Comment: Если вы находитесь до первой строчки `create`, то этот объект ещё не создался. В общем, по-моему вам ещё рано в Rails. Вы ещё даже в Ruby толком не освоились.

Comment: согласен, но все равно хочу разобраться) спасибо за помощь !) я уже понял логику, объект создается не при new, а когда уже save идет...